# Inconsistent MSDN documentation for InterlockedExchange() type functions/intrinsics?

Tags: c, visual-c++, x86, intrinsics, lock-free

First, we have InterlockedExchange64();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
LONGLONG __cdecl InterlockedExchange64( __inout LONGLONG volatile *Target, __in LONGLONG Value );
```

Second, we have the compiler intrinsic, _InterlockedExchange64(), note the absence of volatile;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s26w950%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
__int64 _InterlockedExchange64( __int64 * Target, __int64 Value );
```

Next, we have InterlockedExchangePointer() which like InterlockedExchange64(), uses volatile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
PVOID __cdecl InterlockedExchangePointer( __inout  PVOID volatile *Target, __in PVOID Value );
```

But now we come to the intrinsic for pointer exchange, _InterlockedExchangePointer() and here we see volatile used!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/853x471w.aspx

```
void * _InterlockedExchangePointer( void * volatile * Target, void * Value );
```

The underlying instruction is the same in all cases, so what gives?  documentation error?

The GCC instrincs don't mention volatile for exchange, but then they don't mention it for CAS either!  so that doesn't help.

My view is that a CAS target is volatile, because you can only know at run time if the exchange will occur; but atomic exchange should not be volatile, because the target is always updated (even if it's value doesn't change), so the compiler has no uncertainty.

I see also the function for InterlockedIncrement() are volatile, but the instrincs are not.  The intrinsics for CAS have volatile for their destinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN is riddled with mostly minor documentation errors (for instance, `__readfsdword` was marked as kernel only under the VS 2005 docs), what you should really pay attention to is the definition the compiler uses, in this case, the definitions in `intrin.h` (taken from VS2010 Ultimate SP1):

```
__MACHINEI(long _InterlockedExchange(long volatile *, long)) 
__MACHINEIA64(__int64 _InterlockedExchange64(__int64 volatile *, __int64))
```

as we can see they are indeed `volatile` pointers that are required.

One final thing to note, all your links are the VS 2005 docs (default linked to by google for older intrinsics), so make sure you use the drop down at the top of the page to switch to the latest versions.

Comment: Have to say I'm puzzled.  Why does exchange require a volatile target?  the outcome of the operation is always predictable.

Comment: @BlankXavier: IIRC it require a volatile target so that it can provide the compiler level memory barrier, while the actual `LOCK` prefixed instruction provides the CPU level memory barrier.

Comment: hmm, yeah - I think I recall volatile changing from VS 2005 (I think) onwards so it has memory barrier semantics, even in C.  But I might be mistaken :-)

Comment: It's not that pointer to volatile is *required* it is that it is *allowed*. That is, if the parameters were declared as long* instead of long volatile* then passing the address of a volatile variable would give this error:

cannot convert argument 1 from 'volatile LONGLONG *' to 'LONGLONG *'

Answer (score 1):

It's not that pointer to volatile is *required* by these function it is that it is *allowed*. That is, if the parameters were declared as long* instead of long volatile* then passing the address of a volatile variable would give this error:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'volatile LONGLONG *' to 'LONGLONG *'
```

This can be seen with this simple code:

```
LONGLONG a;
volatile LONGLONG b;

void DoSomething(LONGLONG* p) {}

int main() {
  DoSomething(&a);
  DoSomething(&c); // Error!
  return 0;
}
```

There is a long tradition in C/C++ of misusing volatile as a way to indicate that a variable may be modified by other threads. This is misguided because volatile doesn't not actually give meaningfully useful semantics for multi-threading, but when C++ didn't acknowledge multi-threading developers got desperate. The problem with using volatile is that it does not prevent compiler or CPU reordering so it it is wrong, say, 99% of the time in multi-threaded code.

Absent C++11 the safe thing to do is to only ever reference these thread-shared variables using Interlocked* functions. If you do this then volatile is unnecessary. Or, use locks like a sane person.

But, since lots of developers tag their thread-shared variables with atomic it is necessary for Interlocked* functions to accept those variables. And that is why they all take the type of pointer-to-volatile.

Comment: Seeing as the question is tagged with MS specific stuff, you'd need to take into account that VS allows `volatile` to give the variable acquire and release semantics (via possibly emitting extra code; except on ARM); see the MS specific portion at the end of the the page on `volatile`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: True - starting with VS 2005 volatile was given MS specific semantics. However VS is now trying to roll those back - the /volatile keyword supports this and its documentation says "We strongly recommend that you use /volatile:iso"

So yes, keeping in mind the VC++ specific meaning of volatile is reasonable for this question. But if you are using volatile for multi-threading you should stop. It's a non-standard usage for it and it requires an entire paragraph explaining under what conditions it is valid (VC++ 2005+, if VC++ 2012 or higher must use /volatile:ms if on ARM).